# Serialize object[] using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, serialization

It is possible to serialize type of object[] using DataContractJsonSerializer?

```
private string TryToSerialize(object toSerialize)
{        
     try
     {
         using (System.IO.MemoryStream writer = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
         {
             System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer se =
                    new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(object[]));
                ser.WriteObject(writer, toSerialize);                    
         }
     }
     catch
     {                
     }
}
```

Comment: ...and what is that the framework says when you try to do?

Comment: What did you found so far? What exceptions are you experiencing when doing it?